# How to type in a symbol looks like \gg but has larger openning angle in latex?

Tags: latex

I don't know how to call that symbol. But I think it is not \gg.

[image]

Comment: [It’s sometimes called ket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra-ket)

Comment: You could try asking this in the LaTeX Stack Exchange site: http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Konrad, according to your tip I find out the solution.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12464/extensible-double-angle-etc